# how to import correctly model and texture

Tags: texturing, import

I downloaded [this model](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/free-1975-porsche-911-930-turbo-8568d9d14a994b9cae59499f0dbed21e) and idk how to import textures and model together as seen on the site.
Just starting don't blast me pls

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: What format does it download in? Does it have textures with the package?

Comment: Use the blender sketchfab plugin
https://github.com/sketchfab/blender-plugin